# How to prevent Rails from creating empty rows on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my migration:

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses, :id => false do |t|
      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true, :null => false
      t.datetime :date_start, :null => false
      t.float :price, :null => false
      t.datetime :date_end
      t.text :description
      t.text :location, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I have my `create` method in my controller:

```
def create
  course  = Course.new(params[:course])
  if course.save
    render :nothing => true
  else
    render "public/422", :status => 422
    return
  end 
end
```

Right now, when I make a call to my `create` method with any data, it creates a new empty row in my `Course` table. However I want to make sure that object that is sent to create is actually a Course object, and that the location and price (for example) are not empty and exist.

I have ASP.NET MVC background, so I am just beginning to learn Rails.

P.S how do I return a success 200 response on successful creation, instead of  `render :nothing => true`?

Comment: What does your Course model look like? Do you have any validations? See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check model validations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated

but as an example:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  validates_associated :books
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would want to put a validation in the model to ensure that you don't create records that are invalid like:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :location, :price, presence: true
  ...
```

In terms of returning a successful response, what you probably want to do is redirect to a `show` page after you are done with your processing like:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @course.save
      format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully created.' }
    end
  end
end
```

Also it's a nice idea to run code to get your object in a method in your controler, which means less duplication of code!:

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course
  ...

  def set_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end
  ...
```

Comment: I am working with angularJS as frontend, so i "need" to return success response

Comment: According to: https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-integrate-angularjs-with-rails-4
looks like you should do `render nothing: true, status: 200`

BTW these days it is a lot nicer to write `render nothing: true` as opposed to `render :nothing => true` personally I think it reads a lot better